# How do I work with an Object in Javascript?

Tags: object, jsonp

I have a getJSON request

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/"+ moveFrom+"&jsoncallback=?", function (result) {

console.log(result);

jQuery(cityFromClass).val(result[0].City);
jQuery(stateFromClass).val(result[0].State);
```

});

That returns the following Object in the console:

```
Object {result: Array[1]}result: Array[1]0: ObjectCity: "VALLEY MILLS"County: "BOSQUE"Latitude: "+31.657441"Longitude: "-097.471686"State: "TX"ZipClass: "STANDARD"Zipcode: "76689"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]__proto__: Object
```

I would like to to use the City and State values returned to set the value of two hidden input fields as follows:

```
jQuery(cityFromClass).val(result[0].City);
jQuery(stateFromClass).val(result[0].State);
```

Obviously I am missing something there as I get the following console error:

**Cannot read property 'City' of undefined**

**Cannot read property 'State' of undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result object printed there where you have

```
console.log(result);
```

Is printing your object out to show that it contains a property result with an array, so to access it you would do

```
result.result[0].City
result.result[0].State
```

Comment: Ah okay. I can see that now.  I totally missed that result object for the result array. Thank you.